# Trying to allocate a struct which contains a set inside of it to heap memory using malloc()

Tags: c++

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Vertex
{
    int state;
    int degree;
    int *neighbor;
    unordered_set<int> neighbors_set;
};
```

I am allocating a bunch of these structs like this:

```
vertex = (Vertex *)malloc(v_n * sizeof(Vertex));
```

but when I try to add an item to the `neighbour_set` of a particular vertex like this:

```
vertex[x].neighbors_set.insert(1);
```

the program crashes.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Don't mix C++ and C API.

Comment: `unordered_set` is not `c`, in general tagging a question with both `c` and `c++` is most of the time wrong.

Comment: @t.niese A question asking about using malloc() for allocating a C++ struct seems adequatly tagged both C and C++. One of the rare cases I could actually agree with both tags. Not starting a retagging war here, I want to convince you.

Comment: @Yunnosch I disagree. Because of unordered set, this is a c++ question. The real answer to 99.9% of why malloc doesn't work in a c++ question is 'don't use malloc'. This answer would not fly in a question marked for c.

Comment: Fair enough. @t.niese Adding the malloc detail to title is however OK for you I hope, considerung it C or not.

Comment: .The problem may come from the value of x : is it to big compared to the number of allocated records (v_n) ?
. The problem may also come from the unordered_set template. What is doing the insert operation ?

Comment: @RachidK. insert operation is using a C++ object which was not constructed

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `malloc()` to allocate C++ classes on heap and expect everything to work. It has not called the constructor for that `unordered_set` like `new Vertex` would have.

You can either change it to using `new Vertex` or at least use the placement new option (which will be like `new(vertext) Vertex`) to properly initialize the object.

P.S.: I missed that you are allocating multiple objects. Either use array new option or better yet, eschew all manual memory management and switch to `std::vector<Vertex>`.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly know about the `std::unordered_set`, so the best advice for solving this problem is to use the c++ lib correctly. In this instance, it seems like you want a vector of your struct with length `v_n`, so, make a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices(v_n);
```

Your access will look the same, and this time it should work.